# Postman eBay API request doesn't work even though it's the same as eBay API Explorer

Tags: postman, ebay-api

So I'm trying to connect to the eBay API and making a simple call. I did the call through the eBay API explorer and it works, but when I copy and paste the call and the headers (seemingly perfectly) into Postman, it gives me a 400 error.

Is there any obvious mistake I'm making?

[eBay Api Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Wq05.png)

[400 Error in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fk3Cv.png)